# How to plot I vs V for multiple circuits in one graph? (NgSpice)

Tags: led, spice

I have to see the I-V characteristics for five different LED model files. I'm using ngspice and I want to plot all five I-V characteristics in the same graph. What do you think I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this for multiple circuits simulated *separately* as well, by using the plotname.variablename syntax.
E.g:

```
*Multiple plots
Vsin 1 0 sin(0 1 1000)
Rsin 1 0 1000
.control
echo Test script
tran 10u 10m uic
*tran1
tran 1m 10m
*tran2
echo $plots
plot tran1.v(1) tran2.v(1)
.endc
.end
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. We can put the various circuits in parallel across the voltage and plotted them all together.